# amqp rabbitmq configuration to run a ruby script by using docker run command

Tags: ruby, docker, rabbitmq, amqp, bunny

I am trying to run a ruby script for backend services by using `docker run` command.

- Adding `CMD ["./bin/ruby_code_name"]` in Dockerfile
- Running `docker run -it --name=containerName --rm testimage` command after building the image.

it shows the following error:

`` E, [2018-07-09T20:09:25.039697 #1] ERROR -- : [amqp] Detected TCP connection failure: Errno::ECONNREFUSED
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/amqp-1.6.0/lib/amqp/session.rb:182:in `block in initialize': Could not establish TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:5672 (AMQP::TCPConnectionFailed)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/amqp-1.6.0/lib/amqp/session.rb:796:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/amqp-1.6.0/lib/amqp/session.rb:796:in `tcp_connection_failed'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/amqp-1.6.0/lib/amqp/session.rb:639:in `unbind'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/eventmachine.rb:1468:in `event_callback'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run_machine'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
    from ./bin/ruby_code_name:216:in `<main>' ``

How can I configure amqp or rabbitmq or bunny to run the ruby script?

Comment: Using 127.0.0.1 or `localhost` in a Docker context is almost always wrong; you need to configure some other name for the AMQP broker, depending on if it's running in another Docker container or somewhere else.

Comment: It's NOT running in another docker container. It's running in my local machine. I added this as environmental variable `AMQP_RECEIVE_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq`. But it does nothing. Do you have any idea? Thanks for your repsonse

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me. All I had to do is:
add this command `CMD ["bundle", "exec", "ruby","filename"]` into Dockerfile and 
add the envFile where I have added the `AMQP` variable value in docker run command